# Underrun notification in Android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, opensl

I am trying to create a streaming based audio application on Android using NDK (which inturn used open SLES). I have the basic streaming setup working.
I need to know how underruns(or overruns) are handled in Android ? How are error callbacks implemented ? How to get the time duration for which the AudioPlayer was starving for data ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

After registering your callback using `RegisterCallback` on your buffer queue's interface, you can call `SetCallbackEventsMask` having `SL_BUFFERQUEUEEVENT_ERROR` as one of your mask bits.

I don't know of any straight-forward method of retrieving the duration for which the AudioPlayer has been starving for data, but you could implement that yourself by handling your own timer and using `GetState` API (also from buffer queue's interface object) in order to obtain the amount of time the buffer queue was empty.

Hope this helps!